# Regular expression for dates

Tags: regex

How would I write a regex for `Sun Mar 05 10:00:47 GMT 2011`

Comment: What language, and what information do you need, what have you tried so far? Also, could this be a homework assignment?

Comment: Chances are that the language you're working in has some function/api to parse such a string into a date-object. So, what language are you using?

Comment: The regex `Sun Mar 05 10:00:47 GMT 2011` fulfils your requirements 100 %. Another one that'll work is `.*`.

Comment: What is the purpose of validating this string? I presume that is not user input.

Comment: @Dev posted an answer on what I presume you're asking. Please share with us the full details, though.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work, I reckon:

```
^(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat) (Jan| ... | Dec) \d\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d (GMT| ... ) [12]\d\d\d$
```